# rails check_box_tag value is NULL

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, checkbox

I am not sure why I am having this problem, maybe I am using the check_box_tag incorrectly.

I have a form that is used to send an email message. You are supposed to be able to choose one or more boxes that represent different groups of people.

```
<%= check_box_tag (:bcc_email, value = @spouses) %> <%= f.label :bcc_email, "Company Spouses" %><br />
<%= check_box_tag (:bcc_email, value = @soldiers) %> <%= f.label :bcc_email, "Company Soldiers" %><br />
```

The values are an array of email addresses. Those work fine, I have had them functioning as drop down menus for sometime.

When I look at the HTML page source the values are there, they are just not being passed along with the create method.

Any ideas?

Comment: You can leave out `value =` in your `check_box_tag` s, it's superfluous.

Answer (score 1):

Ah of course I figure the problem out right as I post this. For anyone out there that makes really obvious mistakes like me:

Since I am using a check_box_tag, I never specified an object. Should look like this:

```
<%= check_box_tag ('message[bcc_email]', value = @spouses) %> <%= f.label :bcc_email, "Company Spouses" %><br />
```